# Add Form control class to a dynamically create Textbox in MCV

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a form control class to a dynamically textboxt created using javascript

View

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("Mobile Number", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2  
  required" 
 })
<div class="col-md-5" id="firstdiv">
  <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" class="form-control" id="txtMobile" 
  onchange="phonenumber()" />

</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <button type="button" onclick="AddTextBox();"><img 
  src="~/Content/Images/SendIT/plus2.jpg"></button>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        var div = $("<div />");

        var textBox = $("<input />").attr("type", "textbox").attr("name", "mobilenumber");

        textBox.val(value);
        div.append(textBox);

        var button = $("<input />").attr("type", "button").attr("value", "Remove");
        button.attr("onclick", "RemoveTextBox(this)");
        div.append(button);

        return div;
    }
    function AddTextBox() {
        var div = GetDynamicTextBox("");
        $("#firstdiv").append(div);
    }

    function RemoveTextBox(button) {
        $(button).parent().remove();
    }
```

The problem I am having is when I click on the image button the dynimically textbox displayed but not in the same format as the first textbox. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to addclass in textbox

```
textbox.addClass("form-control");
```

Comment: Need to be textbox.addClass("form-control"); Thanks Cool JK  for your help